# Quickblox chatRoomDidReceiveMessage is not calling

Tags: ios, objective-c, quickblox

I am facing a problem in which I am not receiving messages while I am chatting in group type `QBChatDialogTypeGroup`. 
I'm using below code message send successfully and received notification other group members but then user in group chat view can't calling these methods then received messages.

```
- (void)chatRoomDidReceiveMessage:(QBChatMessage *)message fromRoomJID:(NSString *)roomJID{

}

- (void)chatDidNotSendMessage:(QBChatMessage *)message toRoomJid:(NSString *)roomJid error:(NSError *)error{

}


QBChatDialog *groupChatDialog = qbchatDialog;

[[QBChat instance] delegates];


QBChatMessage *message = [QBChatMessage markableMessage];
[message setText:txt];
[message setDateSent: [NSDate date]];
message.markable =YES;



message.senderNick=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"name"];

NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
params[@"save_to_history"] = @YES;
[message setCustomParameters:params];


[groupChatDialog joinWithCompletionBlock:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {

[privateChatDialog sendMessage:message completionBlock:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {

     }];
```

Answer (score 3):

Please use addDelegate: method to subscribe to notifications from chat:

```
[[QBChat instance] addDelegate:self];
```

and implement QBChatDelegate protocol methods (optional):

```
- (void)chatDidReceiveMessage:(QB_NONNULL QBChatMessage *)message;
- (void)chatDidReceiveSystemMessage:(QB_NONNULL QBChatMessage *)message;
- (void)chatRoomDidReceiveMessage:(QB_NONNULL QBChatMessage *)message fromDialogID:(QB_NONNULL NSString *)dialogID;
```

[Create new dialog](http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Create_new_dialog) documentation.

Comment: yes i'm already use [[QBChat instance] addDelegate:self]; in viewdidload

Comment: - (void)chatDidReceiveMessage:(QB_NONNULL QBChatMessage *)message;
 this method perfect call in private chat but in group chat below method not calling                                                                                                   - (void)chatDidReceiveMessage:(QB_NONNULL QBChatMessage *)message;

Comment: Have you tried .. ? 
- (void)chatRoomDidReceiveMessage:(QB_NONNULL QBChatMessage )message fromDialogID:(QB_NONNULL NSString )dialogID;

Comment: Please check: http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Create_new_dialog 

Please note: 
chatDialog.occupantIDs - required field

Comment: I don't why the same this happening with me too. But once I Join group chat by calling joinWithCompletionBlock on GroupChatDialog, I start getting the messages.

Comment: @ManojAher In order to send and receive messages from group chat dialog you need to join them first. See http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Chat_in_group_dialog

Comment: Yes, you are right V. Gorbachov, I will have to join every time I start chatting.